# Find $T$ and $T^{-1}$ from Matrix to solve differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

We have the differential equation $y'= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & 4 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \cdot y$

I found out that the eigenvalues are 2 and the jordan normal form is $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

For my next step I need to find $T$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & 4 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ = $T \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \cdot T^{-1}$

How can I find this $T$ (Change of basis)? I got the problem that the eigenvector is$ \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
2x_1 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: The $dim ker(A-2I)$ is $1$ because $A-2I = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & 4 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & 2 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: is this unsolvable?

Comment: By the way, no, $\dim \ker (A-2I)=2$ because that matrix has rank $1$.

Comment: ok youre right but this doesnt help with my problem

Comment: If you decompose the matrix into the sum of a multiple of the identity and a nilpotent matrix, you can compute its exponential without having to find $T$ at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is
\begin{align}
     \mbox{det}\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & -1 & 0 \\
4 & \lambda-4 & 0 \\
2 & -1 & \lambda-2
\end{pmatrix} &= \lambda(\lambda-4)(\lambda-2)+4(\lambda-2) \\
         &= (\lambda-2)(\lambda^2-4\lambda+4) =(\lambda-2)^3
\end{align}
This affords a lot of simplification. The solution of the vector ODE is
$$
             y = e^{tA}y_0,\;\;\; \mbox{where } y_0 =y(0).
$$
The solution may be expressed as a truncated power series:
$$
       y = e^{t(A-2I)}e^{2t}=e^{2t}\left(I+t(A-2I)+\frac{t^2}{2}(A-2I)^2\right)y_0.
$$

Comment: from where do you take $y=e^{t(A-2I)}e^{2t}$ ?

Comment: @Maddude : $e^{tA}=e^{t(A-2I)+2tI}=e^{2t}e^{t(A-2I)}$. The solution is $y(t)=e^{tA}y_0$ where $e^{tA}$ is a matrix function of time that acts on the initial (t=0) vector $y_0$. That's the solution of $y'(t)=Ay(t)$, $y(0)=y_0$.